# How to get file Size from OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

How can I get the filesize of the currently-selected file in my Openfiledialog?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    var size = new FileInfo(ofd.FileName).Length;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With so sparse informations all i can tell you is:

```
new FileInfo(dialog.Filename).Length
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (this.myOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    var length = new System.IO.FileInfo(this.myOpenFileDialog.FileName).Length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**in both mode mitlselect and single select**

```
 if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            if (openFileDialog1.Multiselect)
            {
                long totalsize = 0;
                foreach (string siz in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
                    totalsize += new FileInfo(siz).Length;
                MessageBox.Show(totalsize.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(new FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName).Length.ToString());
            }
        }
```