# FileDialog max size of image C#

Tags: c#

I have created openFileDialog that user is only available to select images: .PNG, .JPG. I want to set max size of those images and if file is bigger than value then popout message box with error. Couldn't find that on google. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Maybe this one will help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872069/how-to-get-file-size-from-openfiledialog

Comment: Thanks @KGB91. Solution in answer.

Comment: No worries! Try to do some more generalised googling next time. :-)

Comment: Note that even a huge image may have a small filesize !

Answer (score -1):

Found solution:

@KGB91 helpful link. Thanks

Code used:

```
var fileSize = new FileInfo(openFileDialog.FileName).Length;
    if (fileSize <= 2000000)
    {
     REST CODE
    }
```